# Can I carry a chef's torch in hand luggage?

Tags: regulations, hand-luggage

I would like to bring a chef's torch as gift for a friend that likes to cook. Although, as I read, you can transport a lighter with you, I am not sure a chefs torch you can.

Its a bit larger than a lighter (at least the one I have, there are the ones larger), and the packaging is still closed.

I have no idea if it contains gas or not. It's the first time I buy such an item. I assume so, but maybe not.

**Can I carry a chef's torch in hand luggage inside european union?**

[image]

Answer (score 22):

According to IATA Dangerous Good regulations, torches are not allowed in carry-on or checked in baggage, nor filled with gas, nor empty, even if unused.

I've heard some airports in EU do allow such items on board, but I've never seen any hard evidence of such cases happening.

Source: Experience, IATA DGR

Answer (score 18):

This kind of equipment is effectively a gas-powered "blue flame" ([oxygen-premixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premixed_flame) burner). Such items are explicitly forbidden by IATA, in both carry-on and checked baggage.

[Source](https://static.compliancetrainingonline.com/docs/DG-Passenger-Crew-Provisions-23A-2013-EN-Addendum1.pdf) (see note at the end of the document).

Also, I own such torch, and it was sold pre-charged.

Comment: I can vouch for this as well. These (generally butane) torches come pre-charged, and also have the option to be re-charged.

Comment: Second link is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Just this Friday I had the pleasure to get an answer to this question first hand, inside the EU.

**Yes you can carry a torch inside Europe (Manchester to Basel flight - EU to Europe)**

It was part of a [Creme-Briulle-Kit](https://cdn.aldi-digital.ie/Cr%C3%A8me-Br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e-Kit_Terracotta-A.jpg?o=S6BiayIcOVbhYzSdeqQDQBfbhyQj&V=hwgC) And I opened the kit, though being a gift, and left the torch's gas fully opened (just in case there was any gas residue)

As expected my luggage was taken to the side, the airport staff opened it, saw the torch being part of the kit, took it and asked someone (I'm assuming someone superior) if I could keep it. Came back and told me, I get to keep it only because there was no gas in it.

Comment: I would be *extremely* hesitant to act on this. Just because you are allowed once or twice doesn't mean the IATA DGR doesn't apply. You just had an exceptionally lenient person. I do not understand the upvotes, frankly.

Comment: @chx Oh yes, because it matters what type of person I get, when it comes to security at the airport. As stated, 1. this happened in the Europe, and 2. the security person went to the head office to ask about the torch, or was the security head lenient too ?. If you ever try to get one trough security, and get different result than mine, then your feedback will be appreciated and on point.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Chicago-Metallic-Professional-6-Piece-Brulee/dp/B000A3N7Q6 Was the Zippo butane canister in it? Or not? If it was just the torch without the canister, then I can understand why it was fine. However, if the torch went through because the canister was supposedly empty, then I would think you got very lucky.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The canister doesn't come out normally so it was one-piece torch. All it needs is a bit of gas and it'd be ready to light that sugar up. Ohhh the zippo refill. No that was never part of my set. All I had was the torch and 4 ramekins, and not a drop of gas in any form around me. I wouldn't dream of trying to pass that much gas past security ... They barely let yo have two pocket lighters for your cigarettes, let alone enough gas to cause a small fire ...